# Combining data from multiple rows into one "summary" row with specific text formatting

Tags: excel, google-sheets

This post is very much related to the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132187/combine-text-from-multiple-rows-into-one-cell-based-on-unique-text-match); however, I was encouraged to ask it again and provide more clarification, as I found the answer to my initial question did not get me what I really needed.

Both my data entry and result sets can each be shown in two ways.  I will show screenshots of each option.

First, my data entry data set can be entered as follows:

[image: Data Entry Set 1]

Next, it can also be entered like so:

[image: Data Entry Set 2]

Note that the SKU patterns are ultimately based upon the concatenation of SKU prefix, color abbreviation, size, and the first letter of the finish.

Based on this data, per SKU prefix into a "summary" row which follows a certain pattern.  Consider the following two options for this result set:

[image: Result Set 1]

And:

[image: Result Set 2]

A couple of points here about my needs which the original post did not address: First, in case it's relevant, this SKU pattern in the result sheets is assembled using data which resides in the data entry sheet and others in some cases, although all of these values are drawn from named ranges from the same workbook. Second, the "Type" column here determines whether a row is a summary row or not.  (Rows with a "Type" value of "Configurable"). Second, note that the position of the summary rows will not be linked to the position of the non-summary rows.

The original post's solution was an elegant combination of FILTERs which accomplished the goal, except for the fact that it was linked to the position of the summary rows and their associated data rows. I'm still hoping that this can be solved using formulas and will not require GAS, as I am quite the novice with it, and my current attempts to start on it have been laughable at best.

Finally, in the interest of being as thorough as possible, I've created a sample sheet showing the methods of entry and result here: [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FC3A5YWY_nnpelG-suthuxciBx0-97bHi5elB0j_5_g/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your time -- all answers and guidance are much-appreciated.

Comment: So you will enter the info in the first screen shot or second and you want the output to look like the 3rd or 4th, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The data on the result sheet(s) will be combined with other data, but I'm looking for that arrangement.

Comment: You might want to edit the title to be something like "How to skip rows with an array formula" or something similar. You might get better answers than what I posted and it is a bit more generic so that others are more likely to see it in the future and find it sounds related to what they are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
Note that you would test it on your data sheet. Your results sheet will end up making it long enough that you exceed the character limits for a formula. You can fix that by taking the common ranges and making them named ranges like A B D (C is reserved). You drag this one down instead of using it as an array. I also changed the delimiter from | to char(10) so it would be easier to read while working with it. Change it back after you confirm it is what you need.

OK, based on that long back and forth this should do it for you.

Helper column:
    =if(B10="Simple",A10&C10&"-"&D10&"-"&left(E10,1),join(char(10), arrayformula("sku=" & filter(A$2:A, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6)) & filter(C$2:C, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6)) &"-"& filter(D$2:D, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6)) &"-"& left(filter(E$2:E, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6)),1) & ",color=" & filter(C$2:C, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6))& ",size=" & filter(D$2:D, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6))& ",finish=" & filter(E$2:E, left(A$2:A, 6) = left(A10, 6)))))

Result Column (Assuming helper column is F ... change it if not:
    =iferror(left(F2,FIND("|\|", SUBSTITUTE(F2, "|", "|\|", LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2, "|", ""))))-1),F2)

Comment: Thanks Rodger.  I'm a little confused by this, but I'll give it a go and report back with steps I took and/or questions.

Comment: Hey @Rodger.  Can you specify into which cell I should try this formula?  When I try it on my data entry sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FC3A5YWY_nnpelG-suthuxciBx0-97bHi5elB0j_5_g/edit?usp=sharing), for example, in A14, I get a circular reference.

Comment: Put it in column F or higher... and I see I copied from row 10 for some reason. So put it in F10 and drag it up to F2.

Comment: Rodger, thank you.  This works perfectly well.  Would you be willing to explain what it's doing at a high level so I can understand it and learn from it?

Comment: I'll need to edit it so that it'll work on the result sheet, but from what I gather, that's just updating references.

Comment: well it starts by looking if you have the row set as simple, if so, it makes the SKU, if not then it would be a configurable row. So it looks at the first 6 characters of the first column and uses that to filter the list so that you have all the simple lines that start with those 6 characters. Then it builds the sku and the explanation of the sku. Most of it is the code that you had in the other answer, just tweaked slightly to make it a single line.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the configurable product from the summary array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... can you show me how it is and how you want it instead?

Comment: Hi, sorry this took a bit.  Figured it was better to highlight the current result and desired result on a worksheet.  Current is formula-driven, desired is copy-pasted with values only, which is my additional step to achieve the solution. The current result occurs whether the summary rows are between each unique range or separated. A final change -- I only need the configurable summary row to show its string if it exists; otherwise, it should be blank as shown.  Here's the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FC3A5YWY_nnpelG-suthuxciBx0-97bHi5elB0j_5_g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You will need to put in an additional layer of filtering or a nested if. I would recommend that you start with a simple formula like =join("|",arrayformula(Filter(A$2:A$12,row(A$2:A$12)<>row()))) and see what you can do. That one will ignore the A column for the row that you are on BUT you will have to continually update the range in a named range or you will have a problem larger than you started with as it will put a | character in for every blank row in your sheet.

Comment: Otherwise you will need a solution similar to this-> (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744937/arrayformula-that-can-skip-rows) or to go with a VBA/GAS script - depending on if your final version is in excel or google sheets.

Comment: Got it.  Yeah, the only problem with the JOIN solution is that the given summary row should have none of the summary rows within it.  So, with the formula as it stands now, if I have P0007C, P0010C, and P0020C and I put the formula in P0007C, I get all of it's simple records, but I also get any other configurable records as well.  If that's the expected behavior of the approach, I'll take a look at the other thread.  Again, thanks a ton for your time and help.

Comment: Well that is the same issue as the other thread also it looks like. I wasn't exactly sure what you were asking to start with and I guess that is it. If you are open to a "helper" column. You could make one that will include that summary row, then add the final column and trim everything after the final |sku so that it isn't there.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I haven't done as good a job of communicating as I had hoped.  A helper is totally fine.  Help says TRIM just gets rid of trailing spaces in this case, so I can use something like MID,FIND,RIGHT combo to find the last "|" in the string, replace it with "", and then TRIM if I understand right.

Comment: Actually, I mis-spoke.  If I enforce a business practice that all skus specific to summary rows will always end in C, then I need to find the first occurrence of a sku fragment beginning with |sku which ends at "," whose last character is "C", then trim all to the right of that so all occurrences of the summary skus are removed.

Comment: OK, edited the answer to include original formula as the helper column and an additional formula to clean up the results

Comment: Thanks again for this.  Does this include your JOIN formula in the comment above to remove the A column value of the current row?  When I enter the two formulas in the first Data sheet with helper in column F and result in column G, I no longer get all of the "C" skus, but I do still get the C sku of the current row.

We can leave this thread be if you'd prefer.  I hate wasting people's time, and you've been kind enough to spend quite a bit on it for me.